# how to use the Jenkins Warnings Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, warnings, jenkins-plugins

I want to generate a compiler warning report for my Jenkins project and here's what I've done so far:
  -installed the Warnings plugin
  -installed the Static Analysis Collector Plugin

Now when I build my project, I see compiler warnings on the console but don't see any sort of report as promised by the Warnings plugin.

Is there any additional configuration required?  Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel really stupid!  My build was failing and hence it didn't publish any report.

Comment: Where did you find the report generated? Even i am looking for the same report.